# Determine if window was opened by window.showModalDialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.opener, showmodaldialog

Does anyone know how to figure out if a window was opened by `window.showModalDialog()`?  `window.opener` returns the parent window when the new window is opened by `window.open()`, but for some reason when you use `window.showModalDialog()`, `window.opener` returns as undefined.  jQuery solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if [window.dialogArguments](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/dialogArgumentsSyntaxandNote.htm) is defined:

```
function isModalWindow()
{
    return (window.dialogArguments != null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually used if(typeof window.dialogArguments != 'undefined') for our specific case, but this got me going in the right direction.